# How to reset desktop

Tags: 10.10

I tinkered with gconfeditor and CompizConfig and something else .. 
Now I can't see the files and folders on the desktop.
And also cannot right click on the desktop.

I tried this:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop false
```

Without success.

Comment: [Solution](http://joesteiger.com/2011/07/02/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-gnome-3-gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-04/)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `show_desktop` key to `false`, then Nautilus will not manage the desktop (i.e. no icons on desktop, no right click menu, etc).  If you set it to `true` instead, Nautilus should handle the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

for Gnome-shell :

Try downloading Advanced Settings (Gnome-Tweak-Tool) and check if

> Desktop > have file manager handle the desktop

is **ON**